# Databasename is current availability (code: 588)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am currently working on asp.net application... I have restored a database and tried to establish a connection string on localhost, connection has been established, but when I run the app in a browser it does not give errors it only says,

> Databasename is current availability (code: 588)

What does it mean and why i browser don't show me the application interface???

Although I have searched it a lot, I cannot find a solution for this.

Comment: please add some more steps to reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please give us some more information on this.

And the error 588 means the following:

"**You can only perform a full backup of the master database.
Use BACKUP DATABASE to back up the entire master database*"

got it from [here](https://www.red-gate.com/supportcenter/content/SQL_Backup/help/7.2/SBU_Errorcodereference)